# Method Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Explain to me please why when I compile this code the result is 0 ? How can it be ?

```
class Parentt {
        int x = 0;
        public void printX() {
            System.out.println(x);
     }
    }
    class Child1 extends Parentt {
        int x = -1;
    }

    public class Foo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Child1().printX();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because you shadowed the variable in `Parentt`

Comment: Beats me.  Usually compiling doesn't return a number.  But if you execute it you'll be printing the value of x from Parentt since Child1 has it's own copy of x (since you declared it again) that isn't visible from Parentt.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot override fields, you can only [hide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e10238) them.

Your `Child1.x` field is hiding the `Parent.x` field.

Fields are resolved based on the declared type on the reference they are accessed on, so

```
public void printX() {
    System.out.println(x); 
    // equivalent to System.out.println(this.x); where this's declared type is Parent
}
```

is referring to `Parent`'s field.

Answer (score 1):

Sotirios Delimanolis basically has said everything that's needed.

However, if you would have defined the printX Method on the child-class (or at least override it), you would get -1 as a result.

```
    class Parentt {
        int x = 0;
        public void printX() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    class Child1 extends Parentt {
        int x = -1;

        @Override
        public void printX() {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

With this example the code

```
Child1 c = new Child1();
c.printX();
```

would return `-1`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Because your variable `x` in your child class does NOT (and cannot) override variable `x` in `Parentt`.  Methods can be overridden, variables cannot, they can only be hidden (which is, in general, bad practice).